# Include phtml in magento CMS

Tags: template, cms, blocks

I'm trying to make different page where i need PHP. thats why i use a phtml file. I don't want to make any changes to the other Magento layouts so I just want to include the phtml file via the CMS.

I've made a phtml file in: mycustomtemplate/template/page/page.phtml

that file contains just 'test'.

then I've tried to call in the magento CMS->new page->content tab with:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/page.phtml"}}
```

but nothing shows up. Is there any way to do this? And how..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is correct, so the issue is theme misconfiguration *or* the "Test" output is being hidden in the browser. View source and confirm that the latter is not the case.

Try creating a copy of the file at `frontend/base/default/template/page/page.phtml` as this template location *has* to work - if the content appears, the issue is theme misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of Magento you're running if you're trying to place the file in the base template - make sure that you're not placing the file in the (now deprecated) default/default path:

**Pre 1.4CE/1.8EE:**

`frontend/default/default/template/page/page.phtml`

**After 1.4CE/1.8EE:**

`frontend/base/default/template/page/page.phtml`

Some extra reading on theme hierarchy from the Magento KB:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy#3.2

Comment: But please don't places files in the base template unless you're an extension developer. Put them in your own package/theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct (I've just tested it). Make sure you created your template file in the correct directory. It should be placed here:

`app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/page/page.phtml`

And flush Magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

You are heading towards right direction. Cache refresh, already purposed, additionally, turn on the magento development mode to make sure your block has been added to the page.

Comment: Always welcome.