# magento home page block not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cms-block

i like to change the home page design in magento(1.9.0.1) for that i added the below code in home page cms block

### code is

content area : 
{{block type="topmenu/homepage" name="home.page" output="toHtml" template="federallawyer/topmenu/home/page.phtml"}}

design area :

### code in block file is

class Federallawyer_Topmenu_Block_Homepage extends Mage_Directory_Block_Data {

}

but i got only the empty home page,your idea and suggestion will help me more.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use following line:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="federallawyer/topmenu/home/page.phtml"}}
```

and make sure you have `page.phtml` file in **template/feerallwaer/topmenu/home** directory.

See this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/include-phtml-in-magento-cms)